# Firebase object returned child_changed into object for DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, firebase

Working on a firebase project where I get data on a child_changed event which I put in a variable.

```js
receipeList = childSnapshot.child('meals/0').val()
```

In the console, with the data in my FB, I get 2 objects as expected.

My question is, how can I get this data in a list or table (anything simple for in the DOM)?
Iterating as follows:

```js
   for(var key in receipeList) {
    var val = receipeList[key];
    var $currentRecipe = $('#contentRecipe');
    $currentRecipe.prepend(
     '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4" id=' + key + '>' + key + '</div>'         + '<div class="col-md-4">' + val +
    '</div>' 
    );
    $currentRecipe.append(
    '</div>'
    );
   };
```

This would get the key and values. Preferably I would like to have the keys just one time (as headers / toplevel list) and the related values per key listed.
Like:

```js
Product | Supplier | {etc}
--------------------------
Appel   | Tree     | ...

Water   | Source   | ...
```

Help much appreciated. I am sorry if I have missed to obvious, but I really have worked my way through numerous tuts and of course questions/answers here.

BTW, I am not (and not looking to do so) working with PHP. My project is entirely build with HTML,CSS and JS on a Firebase database. Implemented so far already quite some items, including DataTables.js. Just this is somehow a hurdle I cannot get paste. Help much appreciated as I just thought myself JS as a career change.

Comment: can you show how _receipeList_ object looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
var receipeList = {key1: "value1", key2: "value2"};

for(var k in receipeList){
    //dynamically create list if not already exists
    if( $("#"+k).length === 0 )
        $("<ul id='"+k+"'>'"+k+"'</ul>").appendTo("body");

    $("<li>"+receipeList[k]+"</li>").appendTo("#"+k);
}
```

[simple DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hznwkLzp/1/)
and [multiple objects DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hznwkLzp/3/)

Comment: Sorry for late response, was tied up in other stuff. And for ignoring first question at all :/  But great stuff, the object was "guessed" correctly and both your solutions (1 on this page, other via the "multiple objects demo") worked perfectly!!  Great help and thanks!

Comment: For other working with Firebase and are also finding there way with it, I have attached a working example below. If you want to check with your own Firebase, just change the reference in the first var.  <a href="https://jsfiddle.net/wcgbvrja/">Firebase</a>